# using join and group by...having giving error

Tags: sql, join, group-by, having

```
  SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_NAME 
    FROM Department d, 
         Student s 
   WHERE d.DEPARTMENT_ID = s.DEPARTMENT_ID 
GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_NAME 
  HAVING COUNT(s.STUDENT_ID) < MAX(COUNT(s.STUDENT_ID));
```

The code is for joining student and department table. The `department_id` is key from department to student. Need to find departments with not the max number of students. Error is group function nested too deeply. Isn't nesting allowed up to 3?

Here is the exact error

> ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?  And what is the **exact** error message (**[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: i guess you need to use COUNT in place of SUM in your having part of the query

Comment: Can you please post the issue (error message) that you have encountered ?

Comment: @VickySelvam same error

Answer (score 0):

*upd*. Oh, shi~! I just mentioned the question's related to Oracle. I don't know its syntax for `rank()` function, but I think it should be really close to Sql Server.

Here it is:

```
;with Department(DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME) as (
    select 1, 'first' union all
    select 2, 'second' union all
    select 3, 'third'
)
, Student(STUDENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) as (
    select 1, 1 union all
    select 2, 2 union all
    select 3, 2 union all
    select 4, 2 union all
    select 5, 3 union all
    select 6, 3 union all
    select 7, 3
)
, DepOrdered as (
    select
        d.DEPARTMENT_ID,
        d.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
        s.StudentCnt,
        -- rank departments by the number of students
        rank() over (order by s.StudentCnt desc) as Rnk
    from Department d
    cross apply (
        -- for every department count its students
        select
            count(s.STUDENT_ID) StudentCnt
        from Student s
        where
            d.DEPARTMENT_ID = s.DEPARTMENT_ID
    ) s
)
select
    DEPARTMENT_ID,
    DEPARTMENT_NAME,
    StudentCnt
from DepOrdered
where
    -- Rnk = 1 would have all departments with max number of students
    Rnk > 1
```